# How do i get windows' view like on Fedora, where pressing super key?

Tags: unity, windows

When I use Fedora if I press the super key I get the view of all the applications i'm using, and it's very comfortable, is there a way of having this on Ubuntu?

Thanks.

Comment: can you show us screenshot please

Comment: btw, when you press super key you get to see and search in dash. I think you cant change this in Unity, its hard coded in unity.

Comment: You need to install GNOME Shell, which is the default shell of Fedora.

Comment: Sorry i wasn't precise, I figured if i put Gnome on Ubuntu it'd work but the question, how do i get it in Unity ? According to Edward i can't do that so it's a shame, i have seen this "task view" in a lot of SO, so i thought there'd be a way in Unity. It's ok, thanks to everybody a lot.

Comment: This is what i wanted to get in Unity; https://www.dropbox.com/s/tvp0yg5gmd21xng/photo31254314260474075.jpg?dl=0  An application's view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, if you want things to function the exact same way as in Fedora, you'll have to use GNOME, not Ubuntu's default Unity.

However, in Unity you can display all the windows open on a given workspace by hitting <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>. If you want to see all the windows on all workspaces, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>, then hit <kbd>W</kbd>.

Holding <kbd>Super</kbd> will bring up Unity's keyboard shortcut list, where these commands and other similar ones are listed. The spread commands can also be configured using the `Scale` plugin of the `CompizCongig Settings Manager`. There you can change the shortcut keys and set hot corners to bring up the window spread.

Comment: Thank you !!!! That's what I was looking for: super+w. Thank you very much!.

Comment: Super key to bring up keyboard shortcut list is really stupid design and a waste.